# Form objects with Elixir and Phoenix framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I wonder if there is a way to create form objects with `Elixir` and `Phoenix` framework? I want to implement something similar to what `reform` gem does in `Rails` because I don't like having same validations run in every case, it leads to a complicated code in my experience.  So could I create something like the following and make it work somehow?

```
defmodule RegistrationForm do
  defstruct email: nil, password: nil, age: nil    

  import Ecto.Changeset       

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, ["email", "password", "age"], ~w())
    |> validate_length(:email, min: 5, max: 240)       
    |> validate_length(:password, min: 8, max: 240)
    |> validate_inclusion(:age, 0..130)        
  end   

end
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can work on a schema with virtual attributes:

```
defmodule RegistrationForm do      
  use Ecto.Schema

  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "" do
    field :email, :string, virtual: true
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :age, :integer, virtual: true
  end

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, ["email", "password", "age"], ~w())
    |> validate_length(:email, min: 5, max: 240)       
    |> validate_length(:password, min: 8, max: 240)
    |> validate_inclusion(:age, 0..130)        
  end   
end
```

This can also work if you specify an `__changeset__` function or value in your struct (this is auto-generated by the `schema` macro.) - however it seems like this may not be an intentional way to do it.

```
defmodule RegistrationForm do
  defstruct email: nil, password: nil, age: nil    

  import Ecto.Changeset

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, ["email", "password", "age"], ~w())
    |> validate_length(:email, min: 5, max: 240)       
    |> validate_length(:password, min: 8, max: 240)
    |> validate_inclusion(:age, 0..130)        
  end   

  def __changeset__ do
    %{email: :string, password: :string, age: :integer}
  end
end
```

Both give the following results:

```
iex(6)>  RegistrationForm.changeset(%RegistrationForm{}, %{email: "user@example.com", password: "foobarbaz", age: 12}).valid?
true
iex(7)>  RegistrationForm.changeset(%RegistrationForm{}, %{email: "user@example.com", password: "foobarbaz", age: 140}).valid?
false
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope it will be useful not only for me

Comment: Can I use this form for nested models? Like, if email and password are fields for a `user` model and age is a field for a `profile` model, that belongs to `user` (and `user` has one `profile`) ?

Comment: @JustMichael The RegistrationForm is not tied to any model. If you want to get the fields out of it for a particular model then you can do: `struct(User, Dict.take(changeset, [:email, :password])`

Comment: @JustMichael Since the changeset protocol is implemented in phoenix_html, your form should work correctly with the changeset, you just need to split the relevant fields out per model as above. Also - I deleted the comment with the link to the post so here it is again for the future http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/08/working-with-ecto-associations-and-embeds/

Comment: Small tip: those models can then just `use Ecto.Schema`. You likely don't need the Model responsibilities like callbacks, only the structure really. Other than that, perfect answer!

Comment: @JoséValim I've updated it to use `Ecto.Schema` - thanks for the tip.